# Как вывести принт если все элементы списка закончились и не отработал if и elif

Tags: python, if

Решаю задачу: Дана строка со словами и числами, разделенными пробелами (один пробел между словами и/или числами). Слова состоят только из букв. Вам нужно проверить есть ли в исходной строке три слова подряд. Для примера, в строке "start 5 one two three 7 end" есть три слова подряд.
Перебираю список и хочу что бы если все элементы перебраны а список закончился выводил False

```
words = "He is 123 man"
    i = 0
    for words in words.split():
        if i < 3:
            if words.isnumeric():
                i = 0
            else:
                i += 1
        elif i >= 3:
            print(True)
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы все же использовал метод isalpha(). И достаточно одного if.

```
words = "He is 123 man"
i = 0
for word in words.split():
    if (i:=(i+1)*word.isalpha())>2:
            print(True)
            break
else:
        print(False)
```

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста запись if (i:=(i+1)*word.isalpha())>2: именно эту часть i:=

Comment: Это ["моржовый" (walrus) оператор присваивания](https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/prisvaivanie-znachenij-python/vyrazhenie-prisvaivanija-znachenij/). Эквивалентен i=, только все в одной строке. Можно расписать в 2 строки: сначала `i=(i+1)*word.isalpha()`, потом `if i>2:`

Comment: @Алексей Р, а если будут знаки препинания, то код будет работать не верно, все нюансы из-за неоднозначного условия.

Comment: Знаков препинания по условию нет: 'Дана строка со словами и числами, разделенными пробелами', а вот число '-1.03e2' может быть

Answer (score 0):

```
words = "He is 123 man"
i = 0
for words in words.split():

    if words.isnumeric():
        i = 0
    else:
        i += 1
    if i >= 3:
        print(True)
        break
else:
    print(False)
```

---

По уточнению [@Алексей Р](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/519463/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%A0) подсчитываем строки, состоящие только из букв,
если в строке есть цифра типа "123a", то счетчик сбрасываем.

```
words = "He is 123 man"
i = 0
for words in words.split():

    if words.isalpha():
        i += 1
    else:
        i = 0
    if i >= 3:
        print(True)
        break
else:
    print(False)
```

Comment: у вас елсе вывалился на строку фор, а он связана с if

Comment: Можете объяснить как замена i = 0 на i = 1 влияет на решение. Не думаю что это верный ответ. Со строкой "He is 123 man" не работает

Comment: Извини не протестировал, i=0, i=1 зависит где счетчик стоит. Поправил если слово без цифр, счетчик прибавляется, если цифры сбрасывается, как только счетчик достигнет трех, выходит из цикла, если цикл не прерывается то возвращает False.

Comment: Метод str.isnumeric() возвращает True, если все символы в строке являются числовыми символами. Поэтому ваш код посчитает строку '123a' словом, что по определению в задаче - *Слова состоят только из букв.* -  неверно.

Comment: Полагаю условие задачи неоднозначное, слова `Дана строка со словами и числами, разделенными пробелами (один пробел между словами и/или числами)` я понял есть слова и есть числа разделенные пробелом. "123а" не подпадает ни под число, ни под слово. Но если есть такое уточнение, строки можно проверять `string.isalpha()`

Comment: В условии точно дано определение слов и нет определения [формата] чисел. Поэтому логичнее проверять слова на соответствие чёткому правилу, нежели числа, правила по которым туманны